# Nesting structures With Datomic

Tags: database, database-design, clojure, datomic

Using Datomic, I'm trying to think of how can I nest a list within a list?

An example Clojure data structure would be something (see *fig.1*). I know that Datomic has the notion of references (ex. in *fig.2*). But those just look like scalar types, not objects (per se).

```
  [{:id 0,
    :symbol DDD,
    :company 3D Systems Corporation,
    :price-difference 1.3100000000000023,
    :event-list [{high 35.11,
                  tickerId 0,
                  WAP 34.491,
                  open 35.07,
                  date 20130426,
                  count 3403,
                  low 33.8,
                  hasGaps false,
                  close 34.53,
                  field historicalData,
                  volume 8667,
                  type historicalData}]}]
```

***fig.1***

```
 {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
  :db/ident :district/region
  :db/valueType :db.type/ref
  :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
  :db/doc "A district region enum value"
  :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}

 ;; district/region enum values
 [:db/add #db/id[:db.part/user] :db/ident :region/n]
 [:db/add #db/id[:db.part/user] :db/ident :region/ne]
 [:db/add #db/id[:db.part/user] :db/ident :region/e]
 [:db/add #db/id[:db.part/user] :db/ident :region/se]
 [:db/add #db/id[:db.part/user] :db/ident :region/s]
 [:db/add #db/id[:db.part/user] :db/ident :region/sw]
 [:db/add #db/id[:db.part/user] :db/ident :region/w]
 [:db/add #db/id[:db.part/user] :db/ident :region/nw]
```

***fig.2***

[EDIT]

Actually, I think I might have found the answer [here](https://github.com/Datomic/day-of-datomic/blob/master/resources/day-of-datomic/schema.edn#L36). I was going through the [Day-Of-Datomic](https://github.com/Datomic/day-of-datomic) code base, and found the example below. But I'm still not clear on what explicitly ties the ***:comments*** namespace to the ***:comment/body*** (or ***:comment/author***)  namespace(s). Does Datomic just use convention to link ***:comments*** to ***:comment*** ?

```
  ;; comments
  [{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
  :db/ident :comments
    :db/valueType :db.type/ref
    :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/many
    :db/isComponent true
    :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
   {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
    :db/ident :comment/body
    :db/valueType :db.type/string
    :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
    :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
   {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
    :db/ident :comment/author
    :db/valueType :db.type/ref
    :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
    :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}]
```

***fig.1***

Comment: Nothing ties :comments and :comment/body. It's just a naming convention. For an example of how to persist a list of lists, see my answer below. I used two random attribute definitions to persist  the equivalent of [["a" "b" "c"]["d" "e" "f"]] in Clojure.

Answer (score 10):

You can't directly persist multi-dimensional lists/vectors but you can use a linking entity to accomplish something similar:

```
;; sample attributes
[{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
  :db/ident :some/ref-value
  :db/valueType :db.type/ref
  :db/isComponent true
  :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/many  
  :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}
  {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
  :db/ident :some/list-value
  :db/valueType :db.type/string
  :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/many
  :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}]

;; [["a" "b" "c"]["d" "e" "f"]]
 [{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/user -1]
 :some/list-value ["a" "b" "c"]}
 {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/user -2]
 :some/list-value ["d" "e" "f"]} 
 {:db/id #db/id[:db.part/user]
 :some/ref-value [#db/id[:db.part/user -1] #db/id[:db.part/user -2]]}]
```

Note that you can use negative numbers to link entities together. They will be replaced by real entity ids when you transact them.

**EDIT**: Starting with version 0.8.4020, Datomic supports nested [component entities](http://blog.datomic.com/2013/06/component-entities.html) (containment relationships specified by `:db/isComponent`) as part of the transaction data. e.g.

```
 ;; [["a" "b" "c"]["d" "e" "f"]]
 [{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
   :some/ref-value [{:some/list-value ["a" "b" "c"]}
                    {:some/list-value ["d" "e" "f"]}]}]
```

The nested maps expand into two sub-entities, both created in the same partition as the container/parent entity. For a full code sample, see https://gist.github.com/a2ndrade/5820364

Comment: I updated my answer to use a new Datomic feature which seems much closer (if not exactly) to what you were looking for. Hope it helps.